# How To Execute XSLT Transform In Liquid Studio Community Edition

Tags: liquid-xml

I checked on the Compare Features page on the website (https://www.liquid-technologies.com/xml-studio-editions) and it says that the community edition does have this feature. However, I am new to this app and cannot find out how to execute it - I have seen in the docs that there is an execute button on the xslt debugger toolbar but this toolbar does not exist in the community edition (as it does not support xslt debugging).

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked this and you are correct.

It looks like it has been removed as it is only on the debug toolbar which, as you correctly point out, is not part of community edition.

This feature will be added back in the next point release.

Comment: That's really great, thanks for sorting :)  

Do you have a rough estimate for when the next point release will be?

Comment: v17.0.2 should be available next Monday (11th March 2019) and will include this fix.